# Use form input to build url with php.

Tags: php, forms

I'm trying to create a form where the user can input their id (username) and it will be appended as a variable in a url that is used in my php script. This is what I have.

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    $id = $_POST['id'];
    echo 'http://example.com/default.asp?action=data&id=$id';
}
?>
<form method="post" action="<? echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">
   <input type="text" name="id"><br>
   <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit Form"><br>
</form>
```

It collects the user's id properly, and if i just echo $id, it outputs the proper value, but when I try to echo the url, it just outputs $id instead of the actual value of the $id variable. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Why not use `GET` method and add hidden fields for other parameters?

Comment: use double quotes for the echo.  or using single quotes and concatenate $id to the url string.

Comment: You should really lookup cross site scripting or XSS on google, currently you have 2 avenues of attack within 10 lines of code...smell

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
echo "http://example.com/default.asp?action=data&id=$id";
     ^---wrong quotes                                  ^--- ditto
```

single-quoted strings do not interpolate variables.

Answer (score 1):

Single quotes won't interpolate the variable, either use double quotes or use string concatenation.... Three options:

```
    echo "http://example.com/default.asp?action=data&id=".$id;
```

or

```
    echo "http://example.com/default.asp?action=data&id=$id";
```

or

```
    echo 'http://example.com/default.asp?action=data&id='.$id;
```

Comment: fixed... sorry, I was typing fast :(

Answer (score 1):

This line:

```
echo 'http://example.com/default.asp?action=data&id=$id';
```

Should be

```
echo 'http://example.com/default.asp?action=data&id='.$id;
```

If you are using single quotes in PHP with a string it will print whatever is inside the string without evaluating anything (ie no variables are evaluated). So you can either use double quotes or append the variable like I did above.